# Egor Khmelev slider works great in FF, not in Chrome or IE

Tags: slider, jslider

Here's the html

```
<span class='sliderholder'>
<input class='dosetup' type='text' id='headletterspace' name='headletterspace' value="1"></input></span>
```

If I initialize in a document.ready with

```
$('#headletterspace').slider({ 
    from: 0,
    to: 30,
    dimension: 'px',
    step: 1,
    onstatechange: function(value) {
        webSetup();
    }
});
```

it works great in FF, but in Chrome and IE9 it shows the slider with no functionality. If I take out that initialisation, leave the same html, and initialise only after an ajax call with

```
$("#headletterspace").slider("value", data[i].WebData);
```

it works in all 3 browsers, but without proper from-to, format, and onstatechange function.

Would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution.  If I take the initialisation code out of the document.ready function and put it in the callback from the .ajax call just above the data line, all works fine in all three browsers, assuming a call to the .ajax function when the page is loaded. This code is in the success callback.

```
if (data[i].WebItem=='headletterspace') {
    $('#headletterspace').slider({ 
        from: 0,
        to: 30,
        dimension: 'px',
        step: 1,
        onstatechange: function(value) {
            webSetup();
        }
    });
    $("#headletterspace").slider("value", data[i].WebData);
}
```